How to prove a Branching Process is transient for all $k>0$ and calculate extinction probability

Consider a branching process $\{z_n\}$. $z_0=0$,
$z_{n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{z_n}\xi_{z_nj}$ and the extinction probability is
$\rho$. $\xi_{ij}$ are i.i.d.
(i). If $\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=1)<1$, prove that all $k>0$ is transient. (Hint: consider two cases: $\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=0)=0$ and
$\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=0)\in(0,1]$)
(ii). Based on the results in (i), calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(z_n \to \infty)$.

For question (i), I can prove that under the first case, i.e.,  $\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=1)<1$ and $\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=0)=0$. Define
$$f_{kk}^{(t)}=\mathbb{P}(z_1\ne k, z_2\ne k, \ldots, z_t= k | z_0=k)$$
and under the first case we have $f_{kk}^{(1)}=\left[\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=1)\right]^k<1$ and $f_{kk}^{(t)}=0, t>1$. Hence under the first case
$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}f_{kk}^{(t)}<1$$
and all $k>0$ is transient state. But what if the second case where $\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=0)\in(0,1]$? It seems unhelpful to calculate $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}f_{kk}^{(t)}$
As for question (ii), I guess the answer is $1-\rho$. However, I don't know how to derive this result from question (i). Moreover, I am really curious about the notation $\mathbb{P}(z_n \to \infty)$. Can someone help? Thanks a lot :)

I think $f_{kk}^{(t)}=[\mathbb{P}(\xi_{ij}=1)]^{tk}$.

(i) when $b:=P(\xi_{i,j}=0)>0$: Because
$$
P(z_{n+1}=0\,|\,z_n=k)=b^k>0
$$
and state $0$ is absorbing, the chain has no states other that $0$ that are recurrent. So each state $k\ge 1$ must be transient.
(ii) from (i):
First,
$$
\{z_n\to\infty\} = \cap_{M=1}^\infty \cup_{N=1}^\infty\cap_{n= N}^\infty\{z_n> M\}.
$$
Because state $k>0$ is transient,
$$
P(z_n=k \hbox{ i.o.})=0.
$$
That is,
$$
P\left( \cap_{N=1}^\infty \cup_{n=N}^\infty\{z_n=k\}\right)=0.
$$
Consequently
$$
P(z_n\in\{1,2,\ldots,M\}\hbox{ i.o.}) =0,
$$
for each $M\ge 1$. Let $B:=\{z_n\to 0\}$ denote the event that the process goes extinct, so $P(B) =\rho$.
Then:
$$
\eqalign{
P\left(B^c\cap\{z_n\to\infty\}^c\right)
&=P\left(\cup_{M=1}^\infty\{z_n\in\{1,2,\ldots,M\}\hbox{ i.o.}\}\right)\cr
&\le\sum_{M=1}^\infty P\left(z_n\in\{1,2,\ldots,M\}\hbox{ i.o.}\right)\cr
&=0.\cr
}
$$
It follows that $P(z_n\to\infty) =1-P(z_n\to 0) =1-\rho$.
